# Execute JavaScript on div change

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts. One asks my backend about new data in database and if there is something new, add this to div with id 'box'. In second script I want to monitorize this and if something is changed in this div, I want to call my function. How to do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            refreshTable();
        });
        function refreshTable(){ //loading data to div
            $('#messbox').load('getData.php', function(){ setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000); });
        }
        function scroll(){ //function to call
            $("#messbox").scrollTop($("#messbox")[0].scrollHeight);
        }
```

Comment: How are you getting this information from the database? Please edit the question and include a text-based [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @Jakub Why you cannot call function you need from `refreshTable`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes in the element's `childList`:

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('target');

const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            myFunction()
        }
    }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, {childList: true});

function myFunction(){
  console.log("Change!")
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<button onclick="target.innerHTML += '<p>Hello World!</p>'">Add something to #target</button>
```

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic since the update, I'm not sure this helps anymore.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic this report "changed!" every time, when my script check updates from database. I added code of all scripts in my post